# UILongPressGestureReocgnizer is not functioning as it should, and kicks in on movement?

Tags: ios, swift, uigesturerecognizer

My understanding is once there is a `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` listener attached to something, e.g. a button, it will fire the selected function, and has 4 default parameters. numbersOfTapsRequired, touchesrequired, min press duration, and allowable movement.

Here's my code:

1) this attaches listener to all backspace buttons:

```
func attachBackspaceLongPressListeners() {
    for button in backspaceButtons {
        let longPress = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(KeyboardViewController.deleteBackwardsLongPress(_:)))            
        button.addGestureRecognizer(longPress)
    }
}
```

And here is the function it fires:

```
func deleteBackwardsLongPress(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) {
    proxy.deleteBackward()
}
```

It works fine in the simulator, but on the actual keyboard app, it is very jerky. I found however that if after you hold the finger down, and then move it around while still holding, the function fires as expected.

Comment: What is the touch event for your UIButtons?  Is it touchDown or is it touchUpInside?  I would try moving between a few UIButton touch events to see if that is affecting the behavior.

Comment: Neither. I simply have a outletCollection for the buttons, and the gesture fires after the default 0.5 second and runs the proxy.deleteBackward()... this is really confusing to be honest

Comment: It seems that the "change" state continuously calls the function?